# How to Login into web based application using Jmeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter

Even though I am passing the wrong credentials(Username and password) to Login ,it is displaying the status as success in the result. Can anybody please help me to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, it doesn't do any extra checks so if you want to ensure you're logged in you should add a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to verify that some specific text is present, like `Hello, %username` or vice versa, that login form is absent or whatever

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article to learn how to conditionally fail JMeter samplers basing on different criteria.

Comment: In Response Assertion, I verified the text present in the Home Page. But still its displaying the status as success.

Comment: If you are passing wrong credentials my expectation is that you should see login page, not home page.

Comment: The problem is If I am giving the URL of Login Page, in the response data I am getting the data of Home Page. Whether I give correct credentials or wrong in the response data I am getting the data of Home Page itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of common issues beginners face! JMeter by default decides success/failure based on the HTTP response code. If you want to fail the HTTP response based on some condition (like some expected text), use [Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion).

I would advise you to read this article on [JMeter Tips for Beginners.](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-tips-tricks-for-beginners/)